# How to change the font size of Open/Save dialogs?

Tags: macos, font

On Sierra ... my Open/Save dialog file listing are displaying in a larger-than-normal font size.

How do I change this?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

In Mojave, at least, Font sizes in Open/Save Dialog Boxes are stored in `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.finder.plist`

The settings for Column View are in `FK_StandardViewSettings:ExtendedListViewSettingsV2`

The settings for Icon View are in `FK_DefaultIconViewSettings`

The settings for List View are in `FK_DefaultListViewSettingsV2`

Relaunch Finder after making changes by holding `alt` and `control` and clicking on Finder's icon in the dock and clicking Relaunch.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on which application is showing the larger text as it may have it's own view settings.  For instance, your Finder window has view settings (accessible from CMD-J or View->View Settings) where you can change the font of the view window to produce exactly the results you are seeing (the default is 12), whereas in Mail you can configure this from the Fonts & Colors section of Mail Preferences.  I know in some programs I've used that those settings are in the data stored in Application Preferences in the Library.

[image: Finder View Options]

If nothing else works and it's system-wide there isn't really a systemwide way to change fonts in macOS but there are some tools out there to help.  You could try [TinkerTool](http://www.bresink.com/osx/TinkerTool.html) to see if that is helpful for you, there is a specific tool to adjust macOS system fonts:

[image: TinkerTool Font Adjustment]

Comment: It's happening in ALL applications; and TinkerTool doesn't help.